# How to scroll to top of page as part of a React event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I add window.scrollto(0, 0) to the componentDidMount function it works great, but adding scrollTo to an event handler does nothing. I have a paginate component (react-paginate) and I want clicking on a new page link to send the user back to the top of the page.

Adding code, but I would say this is more of a general problem then example specific:

```
handlePageClick = (paginate) => {
        Service.get(`${apiBase}/api/profiles`,
            (data) => {
                this.setState({Candidates: data.data, meta: data.meta, selectedPage: paginate.selected});
            }, {page: paginate.selected});
}

                    <ReactPaginate 
                        previousLabel={"<<"}
                        nextLabel={">>"}
                        pageCount={this.state.meta.pageCount}
                        containerClassName={"pagination"}
                        subContainerClassName={"pages pagination"}
                        activeClassName={"active BrandPrimaryBackground"}
                        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                        forcePage={this.state.selectedPage}
                        onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                    />
```

When the user clicks a pagination link (ex. going to page 3), it does an api call and loads up the new values. Since the pagination buttons are at the bottom of the page, I want this event to also send the user back to the top of the screen to see the new results from the top.

Comment: add your component code to help us out a bit

Comment: Added code to clarify